# Brownian Motion stopping time

Tags: probability-theory, brownian-motion, martingales

What is the mean of the stopping time for a Brownian Motion to reach either 1 or -1?

My thoughts: It can be seen that $B_{t}^2 - t$ is a Martingale. And we can somehow use $E[B_{T}^2 - T\mid F_{0}] = 0$ where $T=\min\{t:B_{t}=1\mbox{ or } -1\}$, but I don't know where to go from here.

Thanks

Comment: Next step: $E(B_T^2)=$ $____$?

Comment: @Did I know $E[B_{T} ^2] = E[T]$, but I don't know what to do from here actually.

Comment: @Jojo What do you know about $B_T^2$? (Have a look at the definition of $T$!)

Comment: No, you know that $B_T=$ $__$ or $__$ almost surely, hence $B_T^2=$ $__$ almost surely hence $E(B_T^2)=$ $__$, and this gives you $E(T)$.

Comment: @Did Thanks. Yes, this is where my issue lies. How do we know that $B_{T}$ will reach 1 or -1 almost surely. Is it that, implied from the question, we just assume that one of these will be where the Brownian Motion stops?

Comment: Weren't you asked to prove in a previous question that indeed T is almost surely finite? Then you should concentrate on *this*... Any idea?

Comment: @Did I see. So, since T is almost surely finite, we know that it must almost surely reach 1 or -1 based on the question. It will almost surely reach any boundaries that they tell us in the question.